# How to get Rigidbody2D velocity magnitude x

Tags: unity-game-engine

how to get Rigidbody2D velocity magnitude x.I tried this code.

```
Rigdbody.velocity.magnitude.x
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html), `Vector3.magnitude` is a `float`. You are trying to access it like it's a `Vector3`. In other words, `Vector3.magnitude` does not have a variable `x`.

---

Another issue I see is that you have a spelling mistake in `Rigdbody`. If that is the variable name, you should change it to prevent future confusion and rage. Typically, a c# variable should start with a lowercase letter `likeThis`

---

After taking these both into account, your call should look like this:

```
float magnitudeX = myRigidbody2D.velocity.x;
```

or

```
float magnitude = myRigidbody2D.velocity.magnitude;
```

Comment: note that, `rigidbody2d` and `rigidbody` were deprecated long time ago. you should define your own variables to store references to these components. and also rigidbody will not return an object of type `Rigidbody2d`

Comment: @Bizhan It is implied that they should make their own variable. And using the variable name with or without "2d" is personal preference

Comment: of course, but using rigidbody not only adds one warning to the results, but also can get confused with 3D. it's best to adhere to these rules. I edited your answer to reflect this, and also OP wants the magnitude of the vector in its x axis, so the answer would be `velocity.x` instead of `velocity.magnitude` which I also added to the answer

Comment: Good catch. I meant for "rigidbody" to be a local variable but "myRigidbody2D" is a bit more intuitive.